# Get type information from json for form validation with vue 2

Tags: json, validation, vuejs2

I want to do form validation with Vue 2. The problem is that I want to use information from the server. For each field I can add things like max string length, required, type, ... to the json result.

Does something like this already exists? Is there a common used format for this?

Is there a good plugin for Vue that I can use for this. I already found form validation plugins, but I don't want to bind each setting on each input manually.

I was thinking about a validation object that I could bind to a form. But maybe I'm reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it:

In template, let's say you have something like this:

```
<form>
    <input @keyup="keyUpHandler('firstName')" v-model="firstName" />
    <input @keyup="keyUpHandler('lastName')" v-model="lastName" />
    <input @keyup="keyUpHandler('email')" v-model="email" />
</form>
```

In JS:

```
data: {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: ''
},
methods: {
    keyUpHandler: _.throttle((type) => {
        sendStuffToServer(this[type])
            .then(response => {
                // if there's an error, then show error
            })
    }, 2000)
}
```

I used `lodash` to do debounce, so `sendStuffToServer` will only execute when the user is done typing for 2 seconds. You may come across the debounce filter in Vue, but it's already removed in 2.0, so use `lodash` instead.